# How do I hide the overflow of this category archive on mobile devices,? title effect made by using the following CSS provide by my theme authors

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, customization

I am new to Stack, pardon if my format goes wrong.

here is the CSS I used in my additional CSS fields:-

```
.archive .page-title::after, .page .page-title::before {
content: attr(title);
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
top: -7%;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
white-space: wrap;
display: flex;
align-items: center ;
justify-content: center;
font-size: clamp(50px, 15vw,200px);
font-weight: 800;
line-height: 1;
color: var(--paletteColor7);
text-shadow: 0 0 px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
text-shadow: -px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 1px 0 rgba(0, 255, 170, 0.1), 0 -1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);}
```

I have very little knowledge of CSS and I have tried various solutions from different forums including the Overflow; hidden; attribute.

[image: screenshot of the effect I got]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Add your relevant HTML code too, that'd be helpful

Comment: I tried looking for it but there is no theme editor option in the theme I am using, the authors may have locked it up.

Comment: Can you tell me, where to find the relevant html for this, I am sorry if it sounds silly...I am a non developer.

Comment: If you right click on the page you should see the option to "View Source". It should also be under Developer Tools in the menu for your browser. You need to [add enough code for us to reproduce your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you could also give more details about what you want your end result to be, that would be useful; It's not clear to me what's wrong in your screenshot. The links to the other SO questions you looked at would also help.